# In iOS 9, where is the "Usage" function in Settings?

Tags: disk-space, ios

In iOS8's Settings page, I used to be able to go to "General" then "Usage" and it would tell me how much free space is available on the device, and how much space each app uses.

Where is this now in iOS9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has moved to a little different location. To access the same screen, go to: Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage

Moreover, iOS9 now has a search function inside "Settings". A user can search for a term, such as "Usage" in the search bar to access the corresponding settings.

Answer (score -2):

For iOS9 users the app size can be checked from Setting>general>storage & icloud usages

Comment: This adds nothing that isn't in the accepted answer